# How do I backspace 4 spaces at once in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, spaces, backspace

I know that you can use <kbd>Shift + Tab</kbd>, but isn't there a more convenient way of changing the <kbd>Backspace</kbd>? If you're at the beginning of the line and you <kbd>Shift + Tab</kbd>, you don't go back to the previous line.

Comment: use `Ctrl + Backspace`

Comment: So there's no permanent solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to Tools->Options->Editor->Formatting then remove the check sign from "Use all languages settings" and then remove another check sign from "Expand Tabs to spaces".